# insert value of textbox into database using codeigniter and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I add AJAX code into view part of codeigniter to grab value of input and send it to the controller:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#1").click(function(){

var res = $('#name').attr("value");

$.ajax({

type:"POST",

url:'user/ctrl',

data:{'res':res},

success:function(result){

}

});

});

});
```

In the controller part I added

```
class User extends CI_Controller {


    public function ctrl()

    {

        if($_POST['res']=="yes"){

        $res=0;

        $this->load->model("insert");

        $s=$this->insert->name($res);


        }

        else if($_POST['res']=="No"){

        $res=1;

        $this->load->model("insert");

        $s=$this->insert->name($res);

        }


    }    


}
```

Now I don't know what I should write into the model part to insert value of `$res` into the database.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller u need put this for recieve data from ajax

```
$res = $this->input->get_post('res', TRUE);
```

then...

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

public function User(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('insert','model');
}

public function ctrl(){
    $res = $this->input->get_post('res', TRUE);
    $data = $this->model->functionForInsert($res);
}
```